# SignalR hosted as a self contained application or as a part of a web application

Tags: c#, signalr, self-hosting

I have been reading about `SignalR API` and trying to implement the same. I have created a `MVC` web application which is a client to the `SignalR Hub`. The client is a `JavaScript` client. I have created the `SignalR` Hub as a part of the same application. What I have learnt is that `SignalR` could also be self hosted as an independent application. My confusion is that, does it make any difference if I separate it from my web application and host it separately? And are there any pros and cons to both the approaches.

Comment: It's up to you how you will organize your projects. Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host . (Read the "Overview" part)

Comment: Oh well!! That pretty much answers the question! Don't really know why I skipped that.. Thanks anyway. Maybe if you could put the same thing as an answer by quoting what's given there I could accept it?

Comment: it's there now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you how you will organise your projects. I think there are some interesting points:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host:

> Reasons for not hosting in IIS include:
>
> - Environments where IIS is not available or desirable, such as an    existing server farm without IIS.
> - The performance overhead of IIS needs to be avoided.
> - SignalR functionality is to be added to an    exising application that runs in a Windows Service, Azure worker    role, or other
>     process.
>
> If a solution is being developed as self-host    for performance
>   reasons, it's recommended to also test the    application hosted in
>   IIS to determine the performance benefit.